# JSON Schema Array must contain a specific string

Tags: arrays, json, validation, jsonschema

There are several question on the subject, but none of them seem to address this particular issue nor does the documentation on JSON Schema, so maybe it cannot be done.

The issue is that I have an array that can have any of 4 strings as values, easy enough to achieve with this schema:

```
...
 "attributes": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [   
          "controls",
          "autoplay",
          "muted",
          "loop"
        ]
      },
      "additionalItems": false
    }
...
```

So the values in the array can only be one of those four. Nevertheless, "controls" must always be part of the array, while the other three are optional. If it was an array of objects we could make this required, but I'm not sure how to check for an array having a specific value.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `contains` keyword:

```
"attributes": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [   
      "controls",
      "autoplay",
      "muted",
      "loop"
    ]
  },
  "contains": {
    "const": "controls"
  },
  "additionalItems": false
}
```

From the specification:

> ## [6.4.6. contains](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4.6)
>
> The value of this keyword MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> An array instance is valid against "contains" if at least one of its
>   elements is valid against the given schema.